# maximum number of elements floated left?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a simple booking solution which will be displayed to look like a table, but have coloured rectangle floating over the times they are booked out. The actual database, data entry screens are all done integrated in my solution, I just need to display the data.

First thing I need to do is draw the grid with resource name + 24hours. After much research I've decided to use floating divs in a list as I can use absolute position to position coloured rectangle when a resource is booked out.

I'm trying to draw the first line, the others should be a repetition of this.
I've got the following code, is there way where I can force it to display the entire 'li' in one horizontal line? At the moment, it seems to wrap at 8pm - 11pm on the second line regardless of how much space there is available on the horizontal line. Is there a limit to the number of divs I can float left on a line? Is there also a way to to ensure that if the window size becomes smaller, the divs don't wrap around to the second page, they stay rigid as one line.

Would love to use tables for this one, but research suggests that overlaying coloured divs with absolute position with a different z-index will work far better on a layer of divs than that of a table.

Many Thanks

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.resource-name {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.time-col {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="resource-name">Room A1</div>
      <div class="time-row">
        <div class="time-col">12a</div>
        <div class="time-col">1a</div>
        <div class="time-col">2a</div>
        <div class="time-col">3a</div>
        <div class="time-col">4a</div>
        <div class="time-col">5a</div>
        <div class="time-col">6a</div>
        <div class="time-col">7a</div>
        <div class="time-col">8a</div>
        <div class="time-col">9a</div>
        <div class="time-col">10a</div>
        <div class="time-col">11a</div>
        <div class="time-col">12p</div>
        <div class="time-col">1p</div>
        <div class="time-col">2p</div>
        <div class="time-col">3p</div>
        <div class="time-col">4p</div>
        <div class="time-col">5p</div>
        <div class="time-col">6p</div>
        <div class="time-col">7p</div>
        <div class="time-col">8p</div>
        <div class="time-col">9p</div>
        <div class="time-col">10p</div>
        <div class="time-col">11p</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit for the floating divs, but they will automatically wrap at the end of the line. If you want them to be all on one line, the easiest way is to make them `inline-block` and use `white-space: nowrap;` on their container:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

#container {
 overflow:auto;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.resource-name { 
 border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
 width: 120px;
 height:25px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.time-row {
 display: inline-block;
}
  
.time-col {
 border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
 width: 30px;
 height:25px;
 display: inline-block;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="resource-name">Room A1</div>
    <div class="time-row">
        <div class="time-col">12a</div>
        <div class="time-col">1a</div>
        <div class="time-col">2a</div>
        <div class="time-col">3a</div>
        <div class="time-col">4a</div>
        <div class="time-col">5a</div>
        <div class="time-col">6a</div>
        <div class="time-col">7a</div>
        <div class="time-col">8a</div>
        <div class="time-col">9a</div>
        <div class="time-col">10a</div>
        <div class="time-col">11a</div>
        <div class="time-col">12p</div>
        <div class="time-col">1p</div>
        <div class="time-col">2p</div>
        <div class="time-col">3p</div>
        <div class="time-col">4p</div>
        <div class="time-col">5p</div>
        <div class="time-col">6p</div>
        <div class="time-col">7p</div>
        <div class="time-col">8p</div>
        <div class="time-col">9p</div>
        <div class="time-col">10p</div>
        <div class="time-col">11p</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `width:100%` to your `li`. which will be one line in large screens, then it will adjust according to the screen , because you are `float`ing the `.time-col`

#### Snippet

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  width:100%
}
.resource-name {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}
.time-col {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="resource-name">Room A1</div>
      <div class="time-row">
        <div class="time-col">12a</div>
        <div class="time-col">1a</div>
        <div class="time-col">2a</div>
        <div class="time-col">3a</div>
        <div class="time-col">4a</div>
        <div class="time-col">5a</div>
        <div class="time-col">6a</div>
        <div class="time-col">7a</div>
        <div class="time-col">8a</div>
        <div class="time-col">9a</div>
        <div class="time-col">10a</div>
        <div class="time-col">11a</div>
        <div class="time-col">12p</div>
        <div class="time-col">1p</div>
        <div class="time-col">2p</div>
        <div class="time-col">3p</div>
        <div class="time-col">4p</div>
        <div class="time-col">5p</div>
        <div class="time-col">6p</div>
        <div class="time-col">7p</div>
        <div class="time-col">8p</div>
        <div class="time-col">9p</div>
        <div class="time-col">10p</div>
        <div class="time-col">11p</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If you want always in one horizontal line no matter the viewport  then use `display:table/-cell`

#### Snippet

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.resource-name {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  display:table-cell;
}
.time-col {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="resource-name">Room A1</div>
      <div class="time-row">
        <div class="time-col">12a</div>
        <div class="time-col">1a</div>
        <div class="time-col">2a</div>
        <div class="time-col">3a</div>
        <div class="time-col">4a</div>
        <div class="time-col">5a</div>
        <div class="time-col">6a</div>
        <div class="time-col">7a</div>
        <div class="time-col">8a</div>
        <div class="time-col">9a</div>
        <div class="time-col">10a</div>
        <div class="time-col">11a</div>
        <div class="time-col">12p</div>
        <div class="time-col">1p</div>
        <div class="time-col">2p</div>
        <div class="time-col">3p</div>
        <div class="time-col">4p</div>
        <div class="time-col">5p</div>
        <div class="time-col">6p</div>
        <div class="time-col">7p</div>
        <div class="time-col">8p</div>
        <div class="time-col">9p</div>
        <div class="time-col">10p</div>
        <div class="time-col">11p</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex box if you don't care about old browsers. Easy to handle, always in single line (by default), many options. 
I didn't touch your HTML, but it can be short.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
}
.resource-name {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  height: 25px;
}
.time-row {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.time-col {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="resource-name">Room A1</div>
      <div class="time-row">
        <div class="time-col">12a</div>
        <div class="time-col">1a</div>
        <div class="time-col">2a</div>
        <div class="time-col">3a</div>
        <div class="time-col">4a</div>
        <div class="time-col">5a</div>
        <div class="time-col">6a</div>
        <div class="time-col">7a</div>
        <div class="time-col">8a</div>
        <div class="time-col">9a</div>
        <div class="time-col">10a</div>
        <div class="time-col">11a</div>
        <div class="time-col">12p</div>
        <div class="time-col">1p</div>
        <div class="time-col">2p</div>
        <div class="time-col">3p</div>
        <div class="time-col">4p</div>
        <div class="time-col">5p</div>
        <div class="time-col">6p</div>
        <div class="time-col">7p</div>
        <div class="time-col">8p</div>
        <div class="time-col">9p</div>
        <div class="time-col">10p</div>
        <div class="time-col">11p</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```